# Returning from an Activity started by a Fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

I have an application that uses Tabs. I used Fragments to implement the TabListeners. One of these Fragment starts 2 activities (depending on some buttons).

I used the Eclipse interface to create these activities, meaning that Eclipse took care of all the work (creating the layout, updating the manifest etc.).

I have no issue if I return from the activity using the return button on the phone.
But if I use the "<" symbol on the upper left corner of activity layout, I have an error:

```
01-04 02:56:56.000 E/Activity( 7556): getParentActivityIntent: bad parentActivityName 'com.android.nfcinfo2.FragmentCeSupport' in manifest

01-04 02:56:56.007 E/NavUtils( 7556): getParentActivityIntent: bad parentActivityName 'com.android.nfcinfo2.FragmentCeSupport' in manifest

01-04 02:56:56.007 D/AndroidRuntime( 7556): Shutting down VM**

01-04 02:56:56.007 W/dalvikvm( 7556): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c78b90)

01-04 02:56:56.007 E/AndroidRuntime( 7556): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

01-04 02:56:56.007 E/AndroidRuntime( 7556): Process: com.android.nfcinfo2, PID: 7556

01-04 02:56:56.007 E/AndroidRuntime( 7556): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Activity EvtTransactionActivity does not have a parent activity name specified. (Did you forget to add the android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY <meta-data>  element in your manifest?)

01-04 02:56:56.007 E/AndroidRuntime( 7556):     at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(NavUtils.java:177)
```

But it looks like my manifest is OK (FragmentCeSupport is the parent, EvtTransaction and SeRouting are the child activities):

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/stnfcinfo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.nfcinfo2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.nfcinfo2.EvtTransactionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_evt_transaction"
            android:parentActivityName="com.android.nfcinfo2.FragmentCeSupport" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.android.nfcinfo2.FragmentCeSupport" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.nfcinfo2.SeRouting"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_se_routing"
            android:parentActivityName="com.android.nfcinfo2.FragmentCeSupport" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.android.nfcinfo2.FragmentCeSupport" />
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Here is how I start  the activities from the FragmentCeSupport:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.evt_tx_button:
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EvtTransactionActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
        break;

    case R.id.routing_host_button:
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SeRouting.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
        break;
    }
}
```

And here is the return code (generated by Eclipse) in EvtTransactionActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html. check this

Comment: Just finished to read it and found nothing that solves my issue. I already have all the code listed there and I am not in the case "Navigate up with a new back stack".

Comment: You have not understood the docs. did you read specifying the parent activtiy topic?

Comment: May be a little more explanations here? What did I not understood?

Comment: read the topic `Specify the Parent Activity`

Comment: Ok I just finished to read it. It is a quite short topic, which describes exactly what I have in my manifest. I would like to understand my error, but I am lost here...

Comment: Your fragment is specified as a parent activity name in the xml. Instead, you should specify the activty which you added the fragment called "FragmentCeSupport". I think you added FragmentCeSupport to your MainActivity. That's why you specify MainAcitvity as a parent activity of EvtTransactionActivity and SeRouting in your manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Activity EvtTransactionActivity does not have a parent activity name specified. (Did you forget to add the android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY <meta-data>  element in your manifest?)
```

Change

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.nfcinfo2.EvtTransactionActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_evt_transaction"
        android:parentActivityName="com.android.nfcinfo2.FragmentCeSupport" >// is this the activity you want to go to. i guess this is a fragment
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.android.nfcinfo2.FragmentCeSupport" />
    </activity>
```

to

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.nfcinfo2.EvtTransactionActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.android.nfcinfo2.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.android.nfcinfo2.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: THnaks for your answer.

Comment: @user2909967 you need to specify the activity which should be parent not fragment. its the same for other activity as well. let me know if it works

Comment: Is this because Fragment is not an activity? And the only parent activity is MainActivity?

Comment: OK you just answer my question. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2909967 yes fragment is hosted by a activity. you navigate from from activtiy to another. mark the answer as correct if it helps by clicking the tick once

Comment: Sorry it seems I do not have enough reputation to do that but your answer definitely helps.

Comment: It still does not go to the exact Fragment from where you left that screen. For example if 2 or more fragments were hosted in that Activity and this solution only starts the Activity and by default the Fragment which you've declared as default will be inflated. What if we had to inflate the exact fragment from where we left initially. This solution fails then.

Comment: @LokeshKumar you need to change your code for that. After all fragment is hosted by a Activity. By the way the error posted by op has nothing to do with fragments. Also downvote on this is not warranted coz your situation is different from op's error. this solution is not for your situation. Pls ask a different question and i will be happy to answer

Answer (score 7):

If you want to back from a child activity to Fragment put the following code in your Manifest File

```
  android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Comment: Thanks man. This is exactly what I was missing. Need to read more about the launchModes.